# MS Chart Stack Columns overshot plotting point

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart, stacked-chart

While attempting to plot a stacked columns chart, I noticed that for multiple series with only 2 valid data points in one of the series, the chart appears wrong:

[image]

The code used to generate is the same as the one in the question I previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816395/why-do-chart-stacked-columns-show-up-as-thin-lines). Anyone can help? Not sure what other details are needed to solve this, so I will provide more info if necessary..

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 1):

In a `Chart` all Column-types by default fill the available space with the available `DataPoints` and when only a few `DataPoints` are there, their columns become ridiculously fat..

You have two options:

- You could add dummy points to each `X-Value` where the `DataPoints` are missing; the dummies should have `Y-Values` of `0`
- Much simpler: You can controls the Column Width. The only difficulties are to decide on a width and of course finding the well-hidden 'custom-property'

**Note**: For either of to work well, you need to have a clear concept of which `X-Values` you will have! If you only add points when they happen to come along you either won't be able to add the 'missing' dummies or to control the `X-Axis` range..

[image]

[image]

The examples show one year with one `DataPoint` per month.

Here is a code example for both options:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    Series S = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
    S.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    Random R = new Random(123);
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-01-01");
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yy";
    for (int m = 1; m < 12; m++)
    {
        // This can be a real or a dummy point, depending on a simple condition..
        S.Points.AddXY(dt.AddMonths(m), (m <= 2) ? R.Next(100): 0);
    }
}
```

Here we add only two points but control the column width in **pixels**. In addition we set a `Maximum` to the `X-Axis`, so that is show the full 12 months range. To do so we need to **calculate** the `DateTime` of the maximum and the **convert** it to `double`..:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    Series S = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
    S.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    S.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "20"); // <- control the column width in pixels

    Random R = new Random(123);
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-01-01");
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yy";
    for (int m = 1; m < 12; m++)
    {
        // here we add only a few points:
        if (m <= 2) S.Points.AddXY(dt.AddMonths(m), R.Next(100));  
    }
    // to control the displayed time range we set a Maximum
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = dt.AddMonths(12).ToOADate();
}
```

**Note**: In the second example since the width is set in **pixels** it will not **scale** with the `Chart`! This means that if you make the chart very small the columns will overlap!

So if you want scaling you may want have to **calculate** it on every `SizeChanged` event.. For this calculation you will have to know just how many `DataPoints` the chart should be **able** to display; you can't use the `Points.Count` values since you are missing so many points..

Here is an example of such a scaling code:

```
private void chart1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pointCount = 12;
    float columnwidth = 0.3f;
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    int width = (int)(1f * chart1.ClientSize.Width * 
                      CA.InnerPlotPosition.Width / 100f  / pointCount * columnwidth );
    chart1.Series[0].SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "" + width);
}
```

Note that all chart `Position` values are in **percent** of the chart `ClientSize` so we need to use that as a factor..